# UWP app slows, then crashes after certain number of serial writes

Tags: c#, serial-port, uwp, serial-communication, windowsiot

I am making an application using Windows IoT Core on the Raspberry Pi 3.

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino using serial communication. I have used most of the methods shown in this example on GitHub for creating the serial device and writing to it: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialSample/CS.

The program runs fine for the first 130 bytes or so, but then will begin to slow down dramatically after that and crash around the 135th byte or so.

Sometimes it causes the Raspberry Pi to display the Windows 10 "blue screen of death" saying that it needs to restart.

I've tried rewriting the code many ways and using different variations of async, task, and await, but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the code I use to initialize the serial device:

```
private async void setup()
{
    serialPort = await initializeSerial();
}

private async Task<SerialDevice> initializeSerial()
{
    try
    {
        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

        for (int i = 0; i < dis.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dis[i].Name.Contains("Arduino Uno"))
            {
                var serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[i].Id);

                /* Configure serial settings */
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

                // Display configured settings
                //Debug.WriteLine("Serial port configured successfully.");

                // Create cancellation token object to close I/O operations when closing the device
                ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();


                return serialPort;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

and here's the code I use to write to the serial device:

```
private async void sendString(string stringToSend)
{
    try
    {
        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            // Create the DataWriter object and attach to OutputStream
            dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);

            //Launch the WriteAsync task to perform the write
            await WriteAsync(stringToSend);
        }
        else
        {
            status.Text = "Select a device and connect";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status.Text = "sendString: " + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
            // Cleanup once complete
            if (dataWriteObject != null)
            {
                dataWriteObject.DetachStream();
                dataWriteObject = null;
            }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// WriteAsync: Task that asynchronously writes data from the input text box 'sendText' to the OutputStream 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task WriteAsync(string stringToWrite)
{
    Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;

    dataWriteObject.WriteString(stringToWrite);                

    // Launch an async task to complete the write operation
    storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();

    UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
    if (bytesWritten > 0)
    {
        counter++;
        status.Text = stringToWrite + ", ";
        status.Text += "bytes written successfully! (" + counter + ")";
    }       
}
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

### Update

I rewrote my sendString method as this and simplified it using a using statement:

```
private async void sendString(string stringToSend)
{
    using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
    {
        dataWriter.WriteString(stringToSend);
        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        //await dataWriter.FlushAsync();
        dataWriter.DetachStream();

        counter++;
        status.Text = stringToSend + ", ";
        status.Text += "bytes written successfully! (" + counter + ")";
    }
}
```

However, the problem still persists.

Comment: I would imagine your `DataWriter` might be having a few issues. As a rule of thumb, anything that is `IDisposable` (has a `.Dispose()` method), I put in a `using` statement and new up one every time I `use` one. In your code, I can only assume that `dataWriteObject` is a field within the class? If so, I would consider removing it as a field, and `using` one every time you write. Is your `dataWriteObject` a field?

Comment: Thanks, @Geoff. Yeah, I didn't include it in these code samples but my `dataWriteObject` it is a private field within the class.

Comment: I'm not sure on your experience with C# - could you tell me if you've used `using` statements before?

Comment: @GeoffJames, no I'm fairly new to C#. I've been using it for about three weeks. I've only used `using` statements at the top of a file to include namespaces.

Comment: I see. Those `using` are the same as `import` in some other languages. I would suggest removing your `dataWriteObject` as a private field, and creating a `new` one in a `using` block each time you need to use one. I'm not saying this is the exact problem - it might be- but it certainly will help a lot. Use your favourite search engine about using `using` blocks with `IDisposable` objects. As an example: `using (var writer = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream)) { ... // Your code to write in here ... // and end the block when you're finished }`. Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: @GeoffJames, out of curiosity, do you think my problem has anything to do with some sort of buffer filling up? I've tried using the FlushAsync() method before but every time I do I get a NotImplemented exception. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsapps/en-US/c940e0ed-973e-4497-b273-e5ea91287233/uwpstreamoutflushasync-not-implemented?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Not seeing the rest of your code, I'm not too sure where you're flushing the buffer or handling the incoming bytes etc, but looking at that post it looks like other people are experiencing the same with your exception. I think you might have a few problems mixed together and it might be best starting from the top again (if you haven't written too much for already) and stopping at different steps to ensure everything is working OK :)

Comment: @GeoffJames, I've started from the top and rewritten things using the 'using' statement with the DataWriter object, but still not luck. I think the issue is in the serialPort.OutputStream filling up/not getting flushed, not the DataWriter. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: I'm getting a BSOD on Windows 10 (desktop) under similar circumstances.

Comment: @Jeff I haven't tested this on desktop. Unfortunately I'm guessing my solution won't work on a desktop since your only form of serial communication is through that USB port as far as I know. Hopefully you can get it figured out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the UART pins instead of the USB cable to write data, and experienced no more issues. Here's the code I used to initialize the UART bus on the Pi and I used the same function to write as I used above:

```
private async Task<SerialDevice> initializeSerial()
{
    try
    {
        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");
        var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

        SerialDevice serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);

        /* Configure serial settings */
        serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

        status.Text = "Serial port configured succesfully.";

        return serialPort;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    status.Text = "Serial port not configured successfully. Are you sure a serial device is connected?";
    return null;
}
```

This doesn't exactly answer the problem with sending data over the USB cable, but I'm posting it here in case anyone has a similar problem with using the USB port and would like to try this instead.